# Android - Change SQLite value based on ToggleButton Image

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I want to make an quote app which display the quote, the author, and a fav button.

I have a custom ListView which has 2 textViews, and 1 Toggle Button

I'm using SQLite with pre-populated data (So i already have all of the data)

I can populate my 2 textViews with my quote (from quote table) and author (from author table) using SimpleCursorAdapter

The Problem is, i have 1 ToggleButton which has:

- Grey Heart image when its not selected (value 0)
- Red Heart image when its selected (value 1)

What i want is

- When the user click on the grey heart image (fav button), the image change to the red heart image and also updates the fav table in SQLite from 0 to 1.
- When the user click on the red heart image (fav button), the image change to the grey heart image and also updates the fav table in SQLite from 1 to 0.
- And when the user exit, and goes to my application again. i want the quotes that the user has already favorited before (value 1) still have red heart image.

Here is the code:

**DatabaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mqn.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quote";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUOTES = "quotesText";
public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR= "author";
public static final String COLUMN_FAV = "fav";
public static final String COLUMN_GENRE = "genre";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

// database path
private static String DATABASE_PATH;

/** constructor (Menambil PATH ke file database) */
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
            + "/databases/";

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean check = checkDataBase();

    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    // Creates empty database default system path
    db_Read = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db_Read.close();
    try {
        if (!check) {
            copyDataBase();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/** Start DB from here */

/** open the database */
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/** close the database */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
    super.close();
}

// insert a user into the database
public long insertUser(String quotesText, String author, String fav) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText );
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a user
public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String fav) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a particular user
public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV },
            COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular user
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all users
public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}

public Cursor getCertain(String valueGenre) {
    String WHERE = "genre = ?";
    String[] VALUE = new String[] {valueGenre};
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV}, WHERE, VALUE,
            null, null, null);
}
```

**quotes_listview (Custom ListView)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtQuote"
        style="@style/QuotesFont"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />



    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heartImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fav"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtAuthor"
    style="@style/AuthorFont"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="New Text"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/text2"-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/text1"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
    <!--style="@style/AuthorFont"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_rowWeight="1"-->
    <!--android:layout_weight="1" />-->
```

**QuotesActivity.java**

```
public class QuotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView quotesList;
DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper;

ArrayList<ListOfQuotes> arrQuotes;
QuotesAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);

    myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    try {
        // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
        myDbHelper.create();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        // open the database
        myDbHelper.open();
        myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    quotesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.genre_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //ALL
            if (id == 0) {
                populateListView();
            }
            //Entrepreneur
            else if (id == 1) {
                populateListViewEntrepreneur();
            }
            //Love
            else if (id == 2) {
                populateListViewLove();
            }
            //Work
            else if (id == 3) {
                populateListViewWork();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });




    //Call Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    //Custom Image Back Button
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_button);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //To make the title from Android Manifest appear, comment the code below
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //Make the app only portrait
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


}

private void populateListView() {

    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getAllUsers();
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txtQuote, R.id.txtAuthor};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);


    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


}

private void populateListViewEntrepreneur() {
    String testing = "Entrepreneur";
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getCertain(testing);
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txtQuote, R.id.txtAuthor};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);

    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}

private void populateListViewLove() {
    String testing = "Love";
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getCertain(testing);
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txtQuote, R.id.txtAuthor};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);

    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}

private void populateListViewWork() {
    String testing = "Work";
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getCertain(testing);
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txtQuote, R.id.txtAuthor};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);

    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}
```